# ASP.Net mobile web page is not working in android

Tags: c#, android, .net

I created a simple asp.net mobile web page using VS 2008. So basically i am using the system.web.mobile. The page works fine in iphone, windows phone. But in android i am receiving unavailable page error. Is there any settings that i need to change for android? Here is my form

```
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="mobile" Assembly="System.Web.Mobile" Namespace="System.Web.UI.MobileControls" %>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
   <body>
    <mobile:form id="form1" runat="server">
    <mobile:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Text="Please select an item to view"    />
    <mobile:SelectionList runat="server" 
     id="SelList1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelList1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
     <mobile:Command id="Command2" runat="server" 
     Text=" Hit Enter to view the details " />
      Name:    <mobile:Label id="lblName" runat="server" />
      Description :  <mobile:Label id="lblDesc" runat="server" />
      <mobile:Command id="Command1" runat="server" 
        Text=" OK " />
    </mobile:form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble getting XHTML to work well on both the iPhone and Android. You may want to just go for an HTML5 DOCTYPE and use adaptive rendering to detect features you want to support.